# Configure spring-boot to auto-configure for only specific dependencies for testing purpose

Tags: spring, testing, integration-testing, spring-boot

I've a `spring-boot` project with `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-data` dependencies in classpath.

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.0.2.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.0.2.RELEASE"
```

Now, I want to test only `spring-data-jpa` related classes. For that I want `spring-boot` to do auto configuration for `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` only. However, if I do `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in `@Configuation` class used for testing, `spring-boot` tries to auto-configure for both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {DataConfig.class})
public class PersonRepositoryTests extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Test
    public void testSaveWithNameNull() {
        /* ... */
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {RepoPackage.class})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {DomainPackage.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {

}
```

**How can spring boot be configured so that it auto-configure for specific dependencies only for testing purposes?**

In my context, I want `spring-boot` to auto-configure only `spring-data-jpa` related configurations omitting `web` related configurations.

Or, **Is there any other better way to setup this type of test configuration in spring-boot?**

Comment: I think there's a typo in your gradle config (4.0.5 of Spring Boot is not available yet, nor is 1.5.2).

Comment: thanks. I was using variables in my project and I made typo while asking question here.

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the version at all if you use the Spring Boot gradle plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already have it. If you use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` and don't specify `@WebAppConcfiguration` then you don't get a webapp and hence there is no MVC layer.

Comment: I added thymeleaf dependencies and when I was testing data-jpa classes, I was getting errors related to thymeleaf something like templates not available.

Comment: Well if you don't have any templates, that is the default behaviour. Surely you can add a directory to your classpath?

Comment: so even if I'm getting errors regarding templates, spring-boot isn't autoconfiguring beans related to mvc, right?

Comment: Could be. It depends on the `@Conditionals`. Why would you care anyway?

Answer (score 7):

Even though the answer above is correct one extra comment.

The `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation starts to auto-configure everything what it finds on classpath. You can exclude things via excluding certain auto configuration classes like:

```
@AutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Similarly you can auto-configure just some of the functionality by `@Import` the auto-configuration classes. Like:

```
@Import({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

My real world example:

- I have `@EnableAutoConfiguration` located on my main application `@Configuration` class
- I have a module which uses DB which may be disabled and in that case I don't want to autoconfigure the database at all
- So I excluded the autoconfiguration from main config
- And added the `@Import` on the module config which is guarded by `@Conditional`

Answer (score 2):

There is [@ImportAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ImportAutoConfiguration.html) annotation, that you can use for this purpose.

There is my example in groovy, but you can simple rewrite it to Java:

Config class:

```
@Configuration
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = [HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class])
@EntityScan(basePackages = 'package.with.entities')
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = 'package.with.repositories')
class JpaRepositoryConfig {

}
```

Test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = JpaRepositoryConfig,
initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class) //initializer is for loading config from application.yml
class YourTestClass {
```